# How can I fix the issue of my Flutter app not showing API data?

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart, fetch-api

This is a shopping app in Flutter and I create a controller, model, bindings and provider for fetching and showing API data in application.

this is the controller:

```
class ShopController extends GetxController
with StateMixin<List<NewProducts>>{
  var beveragesList = <NewProducts>[].obs;
  RxBool isLoading = false.obs;
  RxBool noMoreData = false.obs;
  int lastPage = 2;
  int currenctPage = 1;

  final count = 0.obs;

  ShopProductProvider provider;
  ShopController ({required this.provider});

  @override
  void onInit() {
    // TODO: implement onInit
    getProductList(true);
    super.onInit();
  }

  getProductList(bool isLoad) async {
    if(isLoad){
      change(null, status:  RxStatus.loading());
    }

    await provider.getProductlist().then((value) {
      if (kDebugMode){
        print(value);
      }
      List body = json.decode(value) as List;
      final data = body.map((d) => NewProducts.fromJson(d)).toList();
      change(data, status: RxStatus.success());
    }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
      change(null, status: RxStatus.error(error.toString()));
    });
  }
```

this is the provider:

```
class ShopProductProvider extends GetConnect {

  Future<dynamic> getProductlist() =>
      http
          .get(
        Uri.parse('${BaseUrl.baseUrl}/api/homepage'),
        /*headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },*/
      )
          .then((value) => value.body)
          .onError((error, stackTrace) => Future.error(error.toString()));


}
```

This is the model:

```
class NewProducts {
  int? id;
  int? categoryId;
  int? brandId;

  NewProducts(
      {this.id,
        this.categoryId,
        this.brandId});

  NewProducts.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    categoryId = json['category_id'];
    brandId = json['brand_id'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['category_id'] = this.categoryId;
    data['brand_id'] = this.brandId;
    return data;
  }
}
```

AND this is the view:

```
class ShopView extends GetView<ShopController> {

  // final ShopController shopController = Get.put(ShopController(provider: ShopProductProvider()));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: Obx(() =>
   StaggeredGrid.count(
                        crossAxisCount: 2,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 3.0,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 0.0,
                        // I only need two card horizontally
                        children: **controller.beveragesList
                            .asMap()
                            .entries
                            .map<Widget>((e) {
                          NewProducts newproducts = e.value;**
                          return GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              Get.toNamed(Routes.SINGLEPRODUCT);
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                              child: MedicineCard(
                                item: newproducts,
                                heroSuffix: "explore_screen",
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        }).toList(), // add some space
                      )
                      ),
```

... .. ... ... ...

I tried many things like changing the controller, view, or listview, but nothing happened. I think the problem is on my view page. my API data shows like this:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Data Retrive Successfully",
    "code": 200,
    "result": {
        "NewProducts": [
            {
                "id": 1490,
                "category_id": 41,
                "brand_id": 20,
```

but in shop view, it showed like a map list. I think there is a problem, also in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

if data form api is not fetching check that your url is http or https:

if your url is http then you have to do some network config to use the http url in your application for both android and iOS ..

in android go to `android/app/src/main/res`

check if the folder xml exist if not exist create folder with the name and in that folder create a file network_security_config.xml and paste the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://your.url.app.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">https://your.url.app.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
      
</network-security-config>
```

in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file add these line s

```
<application
     android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" // this line
      android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" // and this line
      android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: data is fetching.. I can see data in my android studio run log. I just cant show those data on my application.